# is double safe to use for intent?

Tags: android

I was going to use it as id for an intent, the biggest number the double will ever get to is 50,000 at a max, the intent id will always nearly be full number eg 1, 2, 3, 4, but sometimes it might have id of 1.2, 1.3 would it be ok to use double for this?

Comment: i just want to know if its safe to use double as id for whole numbers and sometimes numbers like 1.2 and 2.3. is it ok thats all i want to know?

Comment: ID for what purpose?? wanna set Extras or what. I dint got ur requirement.

Comment: sorry ya its for extra, and then after it taken out of the extra its used to get info from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes If you are putting extra, You can add , int, double, String, bytes.. etc.. they are pretty much safe.

just at the time of getting Extras from Intent, Take care that you add checks for initial values. so it avoids exceptions.